# Give Edit access for Content Across the Site Collection

Tags: site-collection, sharepoint-permissions

We have a new role coming into the company which is specifically for maintaining stale content across our primary SharePoint Site Collection. In order to do this they'd need to *see* all the content across the SC.

IT doesn't want to give full administrative permissions to this user, ideally just edit-permissions on the pages.

**Is there a way to give view or edit permissions across an entire Site Collection without giving Site Collection Administrator permissions?**

I can make a script to just explicitly add a user or group to everything with broken permissions, but that doesn't encompass new content.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've broken inheritance at any level, you can assign the user as a Group Member (if using SPO Team sites) or as a member of the "Member" level SharePoint Group, which in 2013+ has Edit rights.

If you've broken inheritance, you'll need to add the user to those locations there, as well, if the group you do add them to does not have access.